# Selenium, Python: How to set Firefox driver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, performance-testing, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am testing the following code.

for ex..

```
from selenium import webdriver;
driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:/Users/bharg/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64")
driver.get("https://www.hotstar.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("searchField").send_keys("Movies")
```

I am getting the error as
Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

But I have downloaded the geckodriver and placed the path there.

I am new to this selenium using with python can anyone help me regarding this

Comment: I assume that the isse is because you did not set file path with extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selenium search for browser drivers in the following order,

- Executable Path provided
- Current directory
- PATH

**so you can set geckodriver in the  PATH environment variable , note    that the PATH should be the path to that directory and not gekodriver    itself**

**Or keep geckodriver in the same directory as your script**

**or pass it as executable_path argument to the constructor:**

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver

you can refer the class documentation to see what are the supported named arguments